# Forcing breakpoints in flexbox when element dimensions are unknown?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Before jumping in, let me just show you what I'm trying to accomplish with flexbox, as well as what I've accomplished so far.

## Here's the look I'm going after:

```css
table {
  background-color: #333;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
}

.sidebar1 {
  background-color: orange;
  width: 100px;
}

.header {
  background-color: cyan;
  height: 50px;
}

.sidebar2 {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
}

.main {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

.footer {
  background-color: green;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="sidebar1" rowspan="3"></td>
    <td class="header"></td>
    <td class="sidebar2" rowspan="3"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="main"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="footer"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

## Here's what I've accomplished:

```css
#flexbox_container {
  background-color: #333;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
}

header {
  background-color: cyan;
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 50px;
  order: 2;
}

.sidebar1 {
  background-color: orange;
  order: 1;
  width: 100px;
}

main {
  align-self: center;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: calc(100% - 50px - 50px);
  order: 2;
}

.sidebar2 {
  background-color: red;
  order: 4;
  width: 100px;
}

footer {
  align-self: flex-end;
  background-color: green;
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 50px;
  order: 3;
}
```

```html
<div id="flexbox_container">
  <header>
  </header>
  <nav class="sidebar1">
  </nav>
  <main>
  </main>
  <nav class="sidebar2">
  </nav>
  <footer>
  </footer>
</div>
```

As you can see, I'm almost there. However, my header, content, and footer are sharing the width between the two sidebars rather than stretching to 100%. While this is easily fixed with `calc()` when you know the size of your sidebars, *I do not*.

**Here's the problem:** though in my examples above the width of the sidebars is known, this will not necessarily be the case on my project. I want my header, content, and footer to stretch regardless of the width of either sidebar, whilst still remaining on top of each other.

How do I achieve my desired look using flexbox, and only flexbox?

Comment: Well, Flexbox is no _magic wand_, and can't do that when you have unknown sizes of elements. In this case you need to wrap the 3 vertical stacked element to solve that, so is that an option?

Comment: Somehow, wrapping those elements didn't even occur to me. I'll see if someone else comes up with a better way, but that's definitely a workable solution.

Comment: No one will, as their is no way doing that as is....with unknown sizes

Comment: I also added a second sample, with no fixed size, so you can see how it behaves when sized by content

Comment: Please review and comment on my answer, and let me know if something is unclear or missing.

Comment: Sorry—I've been sidetracked. I went with your solution, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you change your markup a little, and wrap the vertical stacked elements, you get this.

```css
.flexbox_container {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #333;
  height: 200px;
}
.flexbox_inner {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
header {
  background-color: cyan;
  height: 50px;
}
.sidebar1 {
  background-color: orange;
  width: 100px;
}
main {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.sidebar2 {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
}
footer {
  background-color: green;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox_container">
  <nav class="sidebar1">
  </nav>
  <div class="flexbox_inner">
    <header>
    </header>
    <main>
    </main>
    <footer>
    </footer>
  </div>
  <nav class="sidebar2">
  </nav>
</div>
```

---

You can also now remove set width's/height's, optimize the CSS some and let it grow with content.

```css
.flexbox_container {
  background-color: #333;
  display: flex;
}
.flexbox_inner {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
header, .sidebar1, main, .sidebar2, footer {
  padding: 10px;
}
header {
  background-color: cyan;
}
.sidebar1 {
  background-color: orange;
}
main {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.sidebar2 {
  background-color: red;
}
footer {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox_container">
  <nav class="sidebar1">
   Side bar 1, wider<br>than side bar 2
  </nav>
  <div class="flexbox_inner">
    <header>
     Header with<br>2 lines of text
    </header>
    <main>
     Content<br>Content<br>Content
    </main>
    <footer>
     Footer
    </footer>
  </div>
  <nav class="sidebar2">
   Side bar 2
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: This solution worked perfectly for me. I also like the use of `flex-direction: column;`, as I finally see an actual good use for it! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest nested flex containers and a slightly modified HTML structure (which needs less settings in CSS)

```css
#flexbox_container {
  background-color: #333;
  display: flex;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.inner {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: stretch;
  width: 100%;
}

header {
  background-color: cyan;
  height: 50px;
  flex-grow: 0;
}

.sidebar1 {
  background-color: orange;
  width: 100px;
}

main {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.sidebar2 {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
}

footer {
  background-color: green;
  height: 50px;
  flex-grow: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="flexbox_container">
  <nav class="sidebar1">
  </nav>
  <div class="inner">
    <header>
    </header>
    <main>
    </main>
    <footer>
    </footer>
  </div>
  <nav class="sidebar2">
  </nav>
</div>
```